# Protractor Execute Tests(within a single spec file) in parallel

Tags: protractor

Hi I have a single spec file with four jasmine tests, like below

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("Test1", function() {
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("Test2", function() {
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("Test3", function() {
```

I have a requirement to execute the tests(within a single file) in parallel, to minimize the execution time. 
I tried  specifying the capability like below

```
  multiCapabilities: {
    split: true,
    maxSessions : 2,
    capabilities: [{
      browserName: 'firefox',
      count: 2
    }]
}
```

but it doesn't workout. Do we have any option to share the tests within a spec file...
like shardSpecTests??

Answer (score 3):

As you've seen, `shardTestFiles` works at the file level. [Protractor](http://protractortest.org) does not currently support parallel runs at the test level.

I see there is a PR for [sharding tests at the suite level](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/2633), eg: `shardTestSuites`. Perhaps the Protractor group would be open to a `shardTestSpecs`, should you write and submit one?

Answer (score 1):

In capabilities:

Allows tests to run in parallel

```
shardTestFiles: true
```

Max amount of browsers

```
maxInstances: 10
```

A hacky way that I use to run test suites in parallel using Grunt task runner is to first create a sub-directory for each test suite. Then create a separate task for each directory to run the specs. Finally create a master task to run all the tasks at once. In this scenario, since you manually shard the tests you want to switch `shardTestFiles: false`